# How to Capture PCM data from microphone in Windows Metro Apps Uinsg C#

Tags: c#, audio, microsoft-metro

Any one help me how to capture pcm data from microphone in windows metro app using C#.

Comment: thanks for reply @RomanR.Actually i goggled lot and dint find any tutorial so i don't have idea about this so can u suggest me how to implement this.

Comment: What about this one: [How to record audio or video (Windows Store apps using JavaScript and HTML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452798.aspx), or this one: [Audio capture in metro apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880569/audio-capture-in-metro-apps)

Comment: Sorry @RomanR. i will try to do this in C#

Comment: [`MediaCapture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.aspx) class there is available to both JavaScript and C#.

Comment: i am used mediaCapture class. but i don't know how to capture pcm data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a C++ component that uses WASAPI, as far as I'm aware this can't be done in only C#.

There's a great working example here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/525620/Recording-audio-to-WAV-with-WASAPI-in-Windows-Stor

The source code for the article is hard to find so here's a link:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/525620/RecordingWavFilesWithWasapiInWindowsRT.zip

I have previously used this in my C# app to allow people to pause their audio recordings.